# Use regex to match Blogger (blogspot) permalinks

Tags: regex, url, blogger

I have (hacked) this regex this far which matches any words between hyphens and separates them, leaving out articles that are 1 character. The reason I need these words separate is that Blogger manages to stop the url at 39 characters AND doesn't break any words.  This works so far:

`^((([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,39})-)+)(?:([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})-)((([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,39})-)+){2,39}$`

Tested against `/wishing-you-a-very-merry-christmas-and-a-happy-new-year.html`
Matches:  `wishing-you-a-very-merry-christmas-and-`
Replacement String: `$1` (not working!!) it results in:

How do I get the 1-letter articles to NOT print in the results regex?  And how do I test for and remove the last `-` in my results?

Comment: I am confused by your pattern. Despite that, I don't think that pattern can match a string that starts with a slash - it matches an ASCII alphanumeric as the first letter, and never matches slashes. I would also advice to remove some of the capturing groups (I've counted 7).

Comment: If you are asking how to match a discontiguous piece of text, you cannot. Extract the whole slug, then replace any words you want to exclude with empty strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot build this with one regex.

The part with max 39 characters in length and not ending with `-` is no problem.

```
^\/?([\w-]{3,39})(?<!-).*
```

See it [on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vo7r)

`(?<!-)` is a lookbehind assertion that ensures that the string is not ending with a hyphen.

But you cannot remove at the same time substrings with the length of 1.

On its own this is also no problem

```
(?<=[/-]|^)[^-]-|-[^-](?=[-./]|$)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vo7u)

Comment: Thank you - with that url it matches perfectly and stops at "...and" but on the other urls it stops at exactly 39 characters - how do I stop it at the last word (defined by hyphens)?